# How to read and add only numbers to array from a text file

Tags: arrays, java.util.scanner

I'm learning java and I have a question regarding reading from file
i want to read only numbers from file that contains strings as well.
here is an example of my file:

```
66.56
"3
JAVA
3-43
5-42
2.1
1
```

and here is my coding:
public class test {

```
public static void main (String [] args){
      if (0 < args.length) {
     File x = new File(args[0]);
    try{     
Scanner in = new Scanner( new FileInputStream(x));
ArrayList<Double> test = new ArrayList<>();
while(in.hasNext()){ 
    if(in.hasNextDouble()){
      Double f=in.nextDouble(); 
      test.add(f);}
    else 
            {in.next();}
}
 catch(IOException e) { System.err.println("Exception during reading: " + e); }
}
```

my problem is it only add 66.56,2.1 and 1 
it doesn't add 3 after "3 or it ignores 3-43 and 5-42
can you tell me how to skip Strings and only add doubles here?
thanks

Comment: "3 is a string. So is 3-43 and 4-42

Comment: You are using `hasNextDouble()`, and hence it skips `3-43 and 5-42` because those two are not doubles.

Comment: can you correct my coding? thnx

Comment: for a file like that, what's the way to separate strings and numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**All the said three ie; "3, 3-43 and 4-42 are strings**

Either u read a string and split it and check for number at **"** and **-** or you put in a space between characters and integers.
The JVM after compilation would treat it all as string if it cannot be converted to a double.
And the File reader wont stop reading till at least a space or a newline.
Hence your code would never work the way you intend it to unless you do as I said above.

Solution 1:
Change your input file to something like this:

```
66.56
" 3
JAVA
3 - 43
5 - 42
2.1
1
```

Solution 2: 
Considering the highly variable nature of your input file I am posting a solution only made for your current input. If the input changes a more versatile algorithm would need to be implemented.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        File x = new File(args[0]);
        try {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(x));
            ArrayList<Double> test = new ArrayList<>();
            while (in.hasNext()) {
                if (in.hasNextDouble()) {
                    Double f = in.nextDouble();
                    test.add(f);
                } else {
                    String s=in.next();
                    if(s.contains("\"")){
                        String splits[]=s.split("\"");
                        test.add(Double.parseDouble(splits[1]));
                    }
                    else if (s.contains("-")){
                        String splits[]=s.split("-");
                        test.add(Double.parseDouble(splits[0]));
                        test.add(Double.parseDouble(splits[1]));
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(test);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Exception during reading: " + e);
        }
}
```

Comment: The first thing is you can change is your input file and to have spaces between those characters.

Comment: Second solution would be to change you code in the else part and check for the " and the - characters and split the input at that.

Comment: for 2nd solution, I know how to check for the " and - but how to split that from rest of array?

Comment: Ill post a solution please wait.

Comment: I have added the solution if you find an answer appropriate please don't forget to up vote and mark it correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can write custom Type Sensor Utility class to check whether the object can be converted to Integer or not. I would approach to this problem like this.

Moreover I can see that you have values like **2.1** and **" 3** to handle these scenarios write additional methods like **isDoubleType()** or **isLongType()** etc.

Also you need to write some custom logic to solve this problem.

```
public class TypeSensor {
public String inferType(String value) throws NullValueException {
        int formatIndex = -1;

        if (null == value) {
            throw new NullValueException("Value provided for type inference was null");
        }else if (this.isIntegerType(value)) {
            return "Integer";
        }else{
            LOGGER.info("Value " + value + " doesnt fit to any predefined types. Defaulting to String.");
            return "String";
        }
    }
}

private boolean isIntegerType(String value) {
        boolean isParseable = false;
        try {
            Integer.parseInt(value);
            LOGGER.info("Parsing successful for " + value + " to Integer.");
            isParseable = true;
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            LOGGER.error("Value " + value + " doesn't seem to be of type Integer. This is not fatal. Exception message is->" 
                                                + e.getMessage());
        }
        return isParseable;
    }
}
```